# transform и background-size

Tags: css

Есть ли `transform`, который изменит не длину и ширину, а `background-size`?
Делаю анимацию через `@keyframes`, и с `background-size` завершение идет рывками. Или есть другой способ?

```css
.pic_dev {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(../img/pic1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: anim_pic_dev;
  animation-duration: 3000ms;
}

@keyframes anim_pic_dev {
  from {
    background-size: 100px 100px;
  }
  to {
    background-size: 100px 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic_dev"></div>
```

Comment: Код покажите свой

Comment: Добавил. Из практики, только transform корректно работает с keyframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так
В данном примере я каждому `transform` прописал `translateZ(0)`, это необходимо для того, чтобы элемент не был мутным (вы можете убрать это и заметите это), можете посмотреть на вариант анимации с background-size, там это будет заметно

```css
.pic_dev {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/rzqucbw.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: anim_pic_dev 3s forwards;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleY(1) translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes anim_pic_dev {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(1) translateZ(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(2) translateZ(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic_dev"></div>
```

Также можно использовать `will-change` для этого и не писать везде `translateZ(0)`

```css
.pic_dev {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/rzqucbw.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: anim_pic_dev 3s forwards;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes anim_pic_dev {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic_dev"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант?

```css
.pic_dev {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('//i.imgur.com/rzqucbw.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: anim_pic_dev;
  animation-duration: 3000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anim_pic_dev {
  from {
    background-size: 100px 100px;
  }
  to {
    background-size: 100px 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic_dev"></div>
```

Если подходит, то используйте `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` - подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Comment: animation-fill-mode: forwards просто сохранит стили последнего ключевого кадра

Comment: @Vanya, `..завершение идет рывками.` - рывок, который я увидел, это добавление `background-size-x: 200px` после окончания анимации. fill-mode, в данном случае, решил эту проблему.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать `animation-timing-function: linear`